# Maxwell Equations for modeling a DC Motor

Tags: motor, dc, dc-motor, equation

[image]I have seen so many videos about this and none helped me.

I can't calculate B. (equation:\$ E = 2*N*area*B*cos(\theta))\$. I mean... when I calculate the field B, I find high values for the current.

my reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ty-H1tQ0-10

I implemented a DC motor and needed to prove the values obtained in practice by Maxwell's equations.

I made the deductions based on the video and unfortunately I haven't satisfactory results.

Comment: Please tell us the timestamp of where in the video you found this equation.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the EE.StackExchange. Some advice and guidelines on how to ask a good question can be found [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): regarding your question, do you need a complete deduction of the formula or do you want to check its correctness?

Comment: This just uses the Laws of Faraday, Lenz, Ampere and Lorenz forces to explain commutation and not to compute the B field strength which depends on V,f L and Ra or DCR for also limiting current and causing losses. continue thru to the 4th video to deal with all 6 motor parameters.

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes. I edited the question again.

Comment: I want to check the formula. I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: I found this equation in 22:36

Answer (score 0):

In the video link you shared, the symbol 'phi' indicates the magnetic flux. Not any angle. Whereas, 'theta-m' means an angle. The equation should be, E=2*NABcos(theta-m). Not 'cos(phi)'. (Though I couldn't find the equation in the video)

I can't say the exact reason for the high values of the current you are getting. But, one thing always should be remembered that while calculating any values from these equations, same System of Units should be used through out the whole calculation, e.g. if you are using SI system of Units, then use it everywhere in your calculation. If you use CGS System, use it everywhere. Convert all the given values in the same Unit system at the beginning of your calculation.

Comment: Roy, this site supports [MathJAX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which you might enjoy for writing your formulas. Use `\$` before and after in-line MathJax or `$$` for large, whole-line MathJax.

Comment: I'm using the same System of Units in the whole calculation, Roy. But thank you!

Comment: Ok. Then something else is causing this error in your calculation.

Comment: Transistor, Thank you for informing me about the MathJAX. This is really helpful.